# Moving view leaves trails when using stroke style

Tags: android

I have an `EditView` class that allows users to move views around on the screen when in edit mode. In addition, I'm drawing a rectangle behind the view to show the user the area of view. Everything works as expected, however setting the paint style to `STROKE` causes trails when moving the view. If I leave the style to `FILL`, I don't have this issue. Is there an explanation to this?

**CustomView Class:**

```
public class CustomView extends EditView {

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // Draw other stuff here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        switch(e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if(!super.onTouchEvent(e))
                    break;
                // Code here
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(!super.onTouchEvent(e))
                    break;
                // Code here
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(!super.onTouchEvent(e))
                    break;
                // Code here
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**EditView Class:**

```
public class EditView extends View {

    private Paint p = new Paint();

    public EditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(MainActivity.EDIT_MODE)
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), p);
    }

    public void setPaintColor(int color) {
        p.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        if(!MainActivity.EDIT_MODE)
            return true;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
        switch(e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Change layout params here
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setPaintColor(Color.RED);
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                setPaintColor(Color.GREEN);
                return false;
            default: return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem: it seems you have to set the stroke width.